# Why I'm getting error indexing in a conditional when mapping an object type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

I'm adding a new property `value:"4"` to the object `Foo`, I have two approches in `aaa` and `bbb`. When hovering over them, both show the same expected result:`{ name:string; value:"4";}`
but there is an error in type `bbb` saying: `Type 'k' cannot be used to index type 'Foo'`

```
type Foo={
    name:string
}

type aaa={
    [k in keyof Foo|"value"]:k extends keyof Foo?Foo[k]:"4"
}

type bbb={
    [k in keyof Foo|"value"]:k extends "value"?"4":Foo[k]
                                                   ^^^^^^
}
```

Why the error? Is it that the conditional in `aaa` being `true` constrains `k` so that `Foo[k]` become valid?

Comment: No, you still have to check for `extends keyof Foo`, why'd you think you don't have to? (I'm lying, it's absolutely not obvious. Just know you always need to `K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never`, it won't infer that itself. Try with `keyof Foo | keyof Bar`, you 'll need two `extends`)

Comment: It's a missing feature of TS, requested at [ms/TS#47810](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48710).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If `k` is something like `"name" | "value"`, then `k extends "value"` is false, and then `Foo["name" | "value"]` is not valid. Of course, in a mapped type, `k` could never be `"name" | "value"`, hence the linked issue above.

Comment: @kelsny ^ that doesn't apply even in the union case presuming `k` (ugh name convention) is a generic type parameter, since it's a distributive conditional type.  But it's definitely tricky

Comment: @jcalz Yep, it's the same issue of the bug report, looks like there is no type narrowing  in the false branch of the conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#48710](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48710).  If you have a generic type `X` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to another type `Y`, then a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `X extends Z ? T<X> : F<X>` the type of `X` is re-constrained to `Y & Z` in the true branch `T<X>`, but it is *not* re-constrained to something like "`Y` but not `Z`" in the false branch.

In general it would not be correct to do so, since there are situations in which `X extends Y` is true, `X extends Z` is false, but `X extends Y-but-not-Z` is *also* false.  For example:

```
type F<X extends { x: string | number }> =
    X extends { x: string } ? X['x']['toUpperCase'] : 
    X['x']['toFixed']; // <-- error!
```

That's flagged as an error for good reason; because you could evaluate something like:

```
type G = F<{ x: 0 | "a" }>
```

where `{x: 0 | "a"} extends {x: string | number}` is true, and `{x: 0 | "a"} extends {x: string}` is false, but `{x: 0 | "a"} extends {x: number}` is *also* false.

So it's not considered a *bug* to fail to re-constrain the false branch, because it's not always warranted.

---

Still, in situations like this where the generic type is constrained to a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and you are checking it against some subset of that union, *and* the generic type is only ever going to be a *single* member of that union (e.g., it's a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) or you are iterating over a set of known keys in a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)), then it would be safe to do it.  It just hasn't been implemented.  So it's a missing feature.

For now the workarounds are to reorder your conditional type as you've shown above, or do a possibly redundant second check:

```
type BBB = {
    [K in keyof Foo | "value"]:
      K extends "value" ? "4" : 
      K extends keyof Foo ? Foo[K] : never;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUB2BDAWwgC4oBnYAJwEscBzdAX3XVEigEEvk1NsBtANJRaUANYQQcAGawEUAD5QARADc8AGwCuEZQF1SwiAA9gEHABMy4yTLmIA-PaF6opZQBZlTFm2gAhQJ4MbCghERwbKVl4RCU1TR19Yj4sI1NzKxV1bV0oJ09lNyh0s0trCWj7fOdBV1IcCFUISgBuH1ZwaBgAHgANKBMyrNQoY1IKGnpFXC0CACMWqEYAPmRUqAGhzOtR8fIqWjplmr7+AHJjc70L4DgAVTBISgBhPDIIa+Kzy+vbuBg1GMEAs13anXYAHEeL09qQAAwzZR4IqrdBAA)